# Texworks and texmf.cnf (export command?)

Tags: compiling, texworks, memory

I created a `texmf.cnf` file on `~\texmf\mytexncf\`. I added the export command `export TEXMFCNF=~/texmf/mytexcnf:` in my source shell files (`.bashrc` and `.zshrc`). Then I ran `texhash`.

When I execute a compilation from the shell, I have not any trouble. But when I compile from texworks, my `texmf.cnf` seems to not be taking into account by the latex command (pdflatex). I tried to add the export command in a `.shrc` command but it's not working.

What shell is executed by texworks?

*CONTEXT:* I compile very large tikz pictures. This is why I have created the `texmf.cnf` file.

Comment: If you are using TeX Live, you don't need to run `texhash` when adding files to your personal tree. Probably TeXworks starts a new shell for a compilation run which likely doesn't read `~/.bashrc`. Better would be to create the file somewhere your TeX installation will look by default anyway. On TeX Live, read the notes at the top of `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`.

Comment: I don't understand why you are altering `texmf.cnf` because you are compiling large TikZ pictures. What changes are you making exactly?

Comment: @cfr Thank you. I have put my `texmf.cnf` in the root directory of my TeX Live installation (on OSX: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/` with `root` rights) as written in `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`. Now it's working!!

Comment: @cfr I plot very large 3D pictures and I need to extend the default main memory of latex processor. See on the `pgfplots` manual section 6.1.

Comment: OK. I turned my comment into something vaguely resembling an answer ;). Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using TeX Live, you don't need to run `texhash` when adding files to your personal tree. However, I wouldn't add your customised `texmf.cnf` there. Probably TeXworks starts a new shell for a compilation run which likely doesn't read `~/.bashrc`.

Better would be to create the file somewhere your TeX installation will look by default anyway. On TeX Live, for example, read the notes at the top of `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`. On a Unix-type system (e.g. Mac OS X, GNU/Linux, BSD etc.) you can get the full path to the file using `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/web2c/texmf.cnf`. On my system, for example

```
echo $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

returns

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

This file includes instructions for how and where to include modified settings. For example, mine says this:

> ```
> % original texmf.cnf -- runtime path configuration file for kpathsea.
> % Public domain.
> % 
> % If you modify this original file, YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST when it is
> % updated.  Instead, put your changes -- and only your changes, not an
> % entire copy! -- in ../../texmf.cnf.  That is, if this file is
> % installed in /some/path/to/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf,
> % add your custom settings to /some/path/to/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf.
> % 
> % What follows is a super-summary of what this .cnf file can
> % contain. Please read the Kpathsea manual for more information.
> %
> % Any identifier (sticking to A-Za-z_ for names is safest) can be assigned.
> % The `=' (and surrounding spaces) is optional.
> % $foo (or ${foo}) in a value expands to the envvar or cnf value of foo.
> % Long lines can be continued with a \.
> %
> % Earlier entries (in the same or another file) override later ones, and
> % an environment variable foo overrides any texmf.cnf definition of foo.
> %
> % All definitions are read before anything is expanded, so you can use
> % variables before they are defined.
> %
> % If a variable assignment is qualified with `.PROGRAM', it is ignored
> % unless the current executable (last filename component of argv[0]) is
> % named PROGRAM.  This foo.PROGRAM construct is not recognized on the
> % right-hand side. For environment variables, use FOO_PROGRAM.
> %
> % Which file formats use which paths for searches is described in the
> % various programs' and the Kpathsea documentation (http://tug.org/kpathsea).
> %
> % // means to search subdirectories (recursively).
> % A leading !! means to look only in the ls-R db, never on the disk.
> % In this file, either ; or : can be used to separate path components.
> % A leading/trailing/doubled path separator in the paths will be
> %   expanded into the compile-time default. Probably not what you want.
> %
> % Brace notation is supported, for example: /usr/local/{mytex,othertex}
> % expands to /usr/local/mytex:/usr/local/othertex.  We make extensive
> % use of this.
> ```

Following these instructions, my modifications are in `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFMAIN)/../texmf.cnf` which includes the following header:

> ```
> % (Public domain.)
> % This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
> % original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
> %
> % That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
> % settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
> % the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
> % And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
> %
> ```

followed by settings for just the bits I want to modify:

```
%%
% ref.: norbert's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262265/
TEXMFARCH = /usr/share/texmf
TEXMF = {$TEXMFCONFIG,$TEXMFVAR,$TEXMFHOME,!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST,$TEXMFARCH}
TEXMFDBS = {!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST,$TEXMFARCH}
```

This should work fine whether you compile from the command line or from within an editor such as TeXworks.