How to add IntelliSense to personal packages in a texmf tree in Latex Workshop?
I am using VSCode with the Latex Workshop extension as my new Latex IDE and I am loving it so far. However, I can't figure out how to add IntelliSense to my personal packages. I have a repository for my University assignments and inside it, I have a texmf tree which contains my packages with custom styles and macros. I set the TEXMFLOCAL variable to point to that directory, so my code compiles and works fine. As an example, here's my texmf tree:

Now somewhere else in the repo I have a document:
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{my-style} % Includes many packages I always use and personal macros

\begin{document}
\Foo % use my personal macro \Foo
\include{bar} % include another file
\end{document}

% bar.tex
\section{Demo}
\Bar % Use another macro \Bar from my-style

I don't get IntelliSense for the \Foo and \Bar macros either in main.tex or bar.tex. I read the wiki page about IntelliSense and it looks like the 4th point suits my case. I tried adding my texmf tree to the latex-workshop.latex.texDirs option. I first tried using placeholders so it doesn't depend on the actual path on my system:
"latex-workshop.latex.texDirs": ["%WORKSPACE_FOLDER/texmf%"]

I also tried to use wildcards to get all the subdirectories, and I tried to give it the absolute raw path too. Nothing worked. I never got IntelliSense for my macros. How can I generate IntelliSense for the macros in my package? If anyone can provide an example on how to set up IntelliSense for my local texmf tree, I'd highly appreciate it.

Is that MikTeX or TeX Live? Because the setup sounds odd if it is TeX Live. You would normally use TEXMFHOME or an additional texmf tree for this and not TEXMFLOCAL which is system wide.

It's TeX Live. I am the only user on my computer, so I don't think it matters if it's system-wide or user-specific. I am new to all this, so if you can suggest a better setup, I'd like to hear it.

The easiest way is to put your custom packages etc. in the directory which TeX Live assigns to TEXMFHOME by default. You can find out where this is using kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME at the command line. (I'm pretty sure this is OS agnostic.) I don't know what IntelliSense is, but it's possible it doesn't pick up the variable, depending how that's set. The other thing is that TEXMFLOCAL is not usually searched directly and, even though you've probably overridden that, possibly IntelliSense doesn't. TEXMFHOME is searched directly by default. Also, if you install the non-free fonts (ctd.)

or do other things which rely on TEXMFLOCAL, you'll end up with these things inside your custom TEXMFLOCAL. That may get confusing later. So even if you don't move the directory, I'd use make it TEXMFHOME rather than LOCAL.

I want this texmf tree to be inside my repo, so it must be an additional tree to the default one. Is it possible to add an additional texmf tree to TEXMFHOME? If so, I can try that. Also, IntelliSense is just a fancy word for autocompletion. I want to get autocompletion for my custom macros like I get for regular latex macros.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262265/.
